# Labels misrendered in this Mapbox Studio Classic basemap

Tags: mapbox

I created a base map with Mapbox Studio Classic, and I'm seeing a problem with how the street labels are rendering at close levels of zoom. For an example, I've highlighted (in yellow) some mistakes in the screenshot below. In some cases the label is just cut off in the middle; in others pieces of the label text are repeated inappropriately. (The two northwest street labels should read "Oakland" and "Maryland".)

[image]

I used the Light template, and the only change I made to it was to color the water blue. The mistakes appear in my original rendering within Mapbox Studio Classic, as well as in CartoDB, where I've loaded the tiles as a custom base map. Reloadings and zooming in and out do not fix the problem -- when I return to this zoom level, the mistakes are still there. And there are many throughout the map, not just the ones in the screenshot.

Is Mapbox Studio Classic still be supported? I'm not using the new Studio for this project because I need to be able to use the base map in Cartodb, which doesn't work with the new version.